# Ordering results of findAll in Node Sequelize not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I had category table has

```
 id    |   name   
    ------+----------
    1     | Test 
    2     | Test 2
    3     | Test 3
```

and I had product table has date column with int value

```
id    |   name | category_id |   data 
------+----------+-------+---------------
1     | proTest | 1 | 10
2     | proTest2 | 2 | 20
3     | proTest3 | 3 | 30
4     | proTest4 | 1 | 40
5     | proTest5 | 2 | 50
6     | proTest6 | 3 | 60
```

using sequelize I want order the category name as per the total count in data column in product table as the product inside each category sorting with its total count I try this but not solve the problem

```
db.category.findAll({ include: [{ model: db.product, as: "products", order: [['data', 'DESC']], attributes: [[db.sequelize.literal('SUM(data)'), 'sumation']],
}], order: [{ model: db.product, as: 'products', order:[['sumation','DESC']]}]
```

I need result to be like that

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Test",
           "sumation":90
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "category_id": "3",
                    "name": "proTest6",
                    "data":60
                },
               {
                    "id": "3",
                    "category_id": "3",
                    "name": "proTest3",
                    "data":30
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Test2",
           "sumation":70
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "category_id": "2",
                    "name": "proTest5",
                    "data":50
                },
               {
                    "id": "2",
                    "category_id": "2",
                    "name": "proTest2",
                    "data":20
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Test",
           "sumation":50
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "category_id": "1",
                    "name": "proTest4",
                    "data":40
                },
               {
                    "id": "1",
                    "category_id": "1",
                    "name": "proTest1",
                    "data":10
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

edit I just try this

```
db.category.findAll({ include: [{ model: db.product, as: "products",
    attributes: ['id', 'category_id','name','data'],
    required: true
}],
attributes: ['id','name', [db.sequelize.fn('sum', db.sequelize.col('products.data')), 'Total_data']],
group : ['id'],
})
```

the result was

```
 "data": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Test",
               "sumation":90
                "products": [
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "category_id": "3",
                        "name": "proTest3",
                        "data":30
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Test2",
               "sumation":70
                "products": [
                   {
                        "id": "2",
                        "category_id": "2",
                        "name": "proTest2",
                        "data":20
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Test",
               "sumation":50
                "products": [
                   {
                        "id": "1",
                        "category_id": "1",
                        "name": "proTest1",
                        "data":10
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

not get all products inside each category

Comment: I advice using prisma.io rather than sequalize.

Comment: it is not available now I had to use sequelize